# jquery treeview selected node path

Tags: javascript, jquery, path, treeview

I'm using [jquery treeview plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-treeview/) to list a directory into a treeview. I need to select path of selected node. for example, have a look at the structure below.

[image]
If **config.php** gets clicked then i need the path like **SITE/classes/config.php**

Can somebody help me to get around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This demo should explain everything, just paste it into body section. Make sure you have jQuery linked on the page.

JavaScript loops through the parent elements and compose the breadcrumb path.

```
<div id="path">click some element</div>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#">SITE</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">classes</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">class.file1.php</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">class.file2.php</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">class.file3.php</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">class.file4.php</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">class.file5.php</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">img</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<style type="text/css">
li a { cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none }
li.active > a { color: red }
</style>

<script>
function getPath(a) {
    var path = $(a).text();
    var $parent = $(a).parents("li").eq(1).find("a:first");

    if ($parent.length == 1) {
        path = getPath($parent) + "/" + path;
    }

    return path;
}

$(function(){
    $("ul a").click(function(){
        $("#path").text(getPath(this));

        $("li.active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).closest("li").addClass("active");
        this.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```